# VB/VBA Variable Declaration Coding Standard - White Space

Tags: vba, coding-style, vb6, standards, whitespace

What is the significance of declaring variables in VB/VBA like so:

```
Private m_sName         As String
Private m_lAge          As Long
```

As opposed to;

```
Private m_sName As String
Private m_lAge As Long
```

I am working on a project which up to now uses the latter, and has done since long before I joined the project.  Two new developers have joined the team and have begun to use the former.  I have seen such pagination previously and wondered; what is its heritage and what advantages/disadvantages does it have?  My own preference has always been the latter and remains so, as much for consistency as anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the days when code editors were much dumber and were little more the text editors it was easier to maintain the "column-style" (the former example) of code.  However even then it could be a pain when changes would require manual re-orginisation of code.

But then intellisense and auto-formatting came along and made it really difficult to maintain the "column-style" formatting code.  Change something in the line and the IDE automatically eliminated "unnecessary" white-space.

I'm all for readability but not to this extent, stick with latter style.

Answer (score 1):

It's only a matter of readability.
Multiple whitespaces in VB/VBA are ignored.

I'd use the former because it's more readable, but Visual Studio has its own formatting rules and will remove extra whitespaces, so I have to use the second form. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a coding convention from old C-days, where you had endless structs and you wanted to see the types and variable names starting in the same column. Do as you prefer!

Answer (score 0):

Easier to read, in my opinion. You can clearly see the variable name and type in the former, whilst the latter becomes more difficult with more variable declarations.